# Appendix Sections Within Chapters, Alphabetically Numbered

Tags: numbering, appendices

I want to have appendix sections that are alphabetically numbered, within chapters:

```
Chapter 1
First Chapter
1.1 First Chapter Section
1.A First Chapter Appendix
1.B Second Chapter Appendix

Chapter 2
Second Chapter
2.1 Second Chapter
2.A First Chapter Section
```

trying this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
  \section{First Chapter Section}
  \appendix
  \section{First Chapter Appendix}
  \section{Second Chapter Appendix}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
  \section{Second Chapter Section}
  \appendix
  \section{Second Chapter Appendix}
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Chapter 1
First Chapter
1.1 First Chapter Section
.1 First Chapter Appendix
.2 Second Chapter Appendix

Appendix A
Second Chapter
A.1 Second Chapter
.1 First Chapter Section
```

How can I fix the numbering?

Comment: You should say, how appendix `section` should be numbered. As `A.1` or `1.1` or just without reference to the chapter they below too.

Comment: @Christian the desired numbering is in the first part of my question.

Comment: Alright, I have missed it, sorry. I will update

Comment: See the update please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works out of the box with the `appendix` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Chapter Section}

\begin{subappendices}

\section{First Chapter Appendix}

\section{Second Chapter Appendix}

\end{subappendices}


\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{Second Chapter Section}

\begin{subappendices}

\section{Second Chapter Appendix}

\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Multiple usages of the `\appendix` command is really designed in `book.cls`, since each time use of `\appendix` will reset both `chapter` and `section` counters and does also change the output of `\thechapter` from arabic numbers to `\Alph` - style.

I've decided to use `\sectionappendix`, that does not reset the chapter counter, but uses `\Alph` for `\thechapter` and restoring `\thechapter` at the beginning of each chapter automatically.

If `hyperref` is used some more action has to be done, i.e. redefine `\theHsection` etc.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\@arabic\c@chapter}}{}{}

\newcommand\sectionappendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \gdef\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Chapter Section}
\sectionappendix
\section{First Chapter Appendix}
\section{Second Chapter Appendix}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second Chapter Section}
\sectionappendix
\section{Second Chapter Appendix}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newif\ifappendixchapter


\makeatletter

\let\latex@@thechapter\thechapter
\let\latex@@thesection\thesection

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  % Restore the original settings for \thechapter and \thesection
  \ifappendixchapter
  \else
  \let\thechapter\latex@@thechapter
  \let\thesection\latex@@thesection
  \fi
}{}{}

\xpretocmd{\appendix}{%
  \let\thechapter\latex@@thechapter % Restore first
  \let\thesection\latex@@thesection % Restore first
  \appendixchaptertrue
}{}{}


\newcommand\sectionappendix{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \gdef\thesection{\thechapter.\@Alph\c@section}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Chapter Section}
\sectionappendix
\section{First Chapter Appendix}
\section{Second Chapter Appendix}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Second Chapter Section}
\sectionappendix
\section{Second Chapter Appendix}

% Real appendix

\appendix

\chapter{First Appendix chapter}
\section{First section in first appendix chapter}
\end{document}
```